# My top bar hover become blurry after changing theme

Tags: wingpanel, icons

Whenever I'm hovering to the topbar application menu or the notification tray it all shows blurry.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all of the themes you can find online support elementary OS also not all of the  ones that support the eOS are written well - so if there is no problem with the default elementary theme, usualy the reason is that the theme you use is not good for elementary OS. In this case you can address the issue to the theme developper or change the theme with a compatible one.